# command line pull request from a fork

Tags: git, github

We follow a development model where devs push to their own fork and create pull requests into the central repo.

My dev team uses a fork based model for version control.

I have two remotes in my project branch, one points to the central repo and one points to my fork. I make changes locally then add/commit/push from the command line. Then I have to open a browser and go to github to create pull request.

Is there a simple command to do a pull request from the command line?

Can I do something like this?

`git request-pull cf2ccd754330da185eb18eb7d60089d9ce78056e central/master cf2ccd754330da185eb18eb7d60089d9ce78056e`

Comment: does this solve by `git request-pull` command between 2 forks ?

Comment: Any news on this thread? I've got stuck with this exact issue where I want to create a pull request from my fork using `gh`. Have your got anywhere with any solutions yet @Shanimal?

Comment: @BrianSalehi No, not that Im aware of. GIT  provides a PR link after each commit now. Which is helpful. At least you can cmd+click the response and jump to the PR page.

Answer (score 0):

Quick search on Google reveiled that there is an extension to git which does exactly what you are asking for. [git-pull-request](https://github.com/tonchis/git-pull-request) I haven't used it but it sounds to be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you give exact command to do `git request-pull` with my `feature-branch` in `myfork` to `master` branch in `center/fork`

Answer (score -1):

**[hub](https://hub.github.com/)** helps complete the [forking workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/forking-workflow)   with the [pull-request](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html#git-pull-request) command.

```
hub --help pull-request  # do this first
                         # practice on a test repo
hub pull-request         # assumes origin on current_branch
git pull-request         # if you are using the git alias
```

<sup>* corporate github users see [**this issue**](https://github.com/github/hub/issues/1180) about adding OAuth token.</sup>